# Scalar extension in tensor product.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\Bbb Q$

a) Show that $\Bbb C$ takes the structure of a $\Bbb Q$ vector space.

b) For elements $\sum'\lambda_i \otimes v_i$ in $\Bbb C \otimes_{\Bbb Q} V$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ define $$\lambda\cdot(\sum'\lambda_i \otimes v_i)=\sum'(\lambda \lambda_i)\otimes v_i$$

Show that $\Bbb C \otimes_{\Bbb Q} V$ has the structure of a $\Bbb C$ vector space

c) Show that for every basis $(v_i)_I$ of V as a $\Bbb Q$ vector space, the family $(1\otimes v_i$ is a basis of $\Bbb C \otimes_{\Bbb Q} V $ as a $\Bbb C$ vector space.

I hate to be someone who just asks for answers, i know this would piss a lot of people off, but after 2 days researching on the internet i still have no idea how to do any of this...Or can someone give me a link where they explain this well?

PS: especially the 3rd question, i dont think i even understand it.

Comment: Who or what gave you the exercise?

Comment: b) is not even a question

Comment: I have edited my b).  Got these from some website...people say the best way to learn math is to do math so....just random questions off of some university website.

Comment: I realise my answer might seem off putting - I say “straightforward” for example, and I know from personal experience (I am a student myself) that this word can be annoying or demoralising: my goal with using this word was to emphasise that you’re probably more able to do a) and b) than you realise. But please, feel free to ask questions. Furthermore, I want to point out that it is only possible to do b) and c) if you have some understanding of what the tensor product “actually is”. If you are having problems with that, I will do my best to address them

Comment: Hey man thank you so much for the answer.... I am towards the end of the semester and there is a lot of papers due (physics student with minor in math) thats why i havnt got to it yet. And not a problem, Straightforward is fine for me, just as long as not "trivial" haha . I will try to solve the problem and @ you again !

Comment: I just went over your profile and some questions you asked here on Stackexchange, you make me feel like an idiot lol...And i remeber your name cuz your helped me out before. Wow ok you are impressive

Comment: No rush. I agree, “trivial” is tempting to use when you are writing and want to save the bother, but it can be incredibly frustrating to see when you are reading, as a student anyway. Regarding the problems, showing linear independence in c) is the most difficult, imo, as you have to really think about what arguments you can make when combining tensor’ed vectors, so try that one last

Comment: I’m glad I’ve helped you before. This must have been through browsing another post I made, do you remember which? Anyway, no, please don’t feel like an idiot. I feel like an idiot myself very often - spending 2 hours obsessing over my working because of one sign error, sort of thing,... but it happens to everyone and happens less over time. We students should try to avoid that feeling of idiocy, it is not helpful or accurate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially an exercise in demonstrating the vector space axioms, in a more complicated and unintuitive setting.

For a) you need to verify that $\Bbb C$ satisfies the vector space axioms when the underlying field is taken to be $\Bbb Q$: we need an abelian group of (vector) addition and for rational multiplication to be compatible (distributive, preserves the identity, etc.) with the (vector) addition structure. Don’t overthink this: this is actually straightforward (rational numbers are themselves elements of $\Bbb C$, which is a field...)

For b), it looks a bit scarier but it’s not. You need to show that the tensor product (the formal sum of the $\otimes$ things) satisfies the vector space axioms when you left-multiply by complex numbers. Conceptually this is more difficult but the real reason why it works is equally as straightforward as part a) (do you even need to worry about the $\otimes V$ part?). Don’t overthink this one either!

For c): we are given a random vector space $V$ whose field of scalars is $\Bbb Q$. We are provided with any basis $(v_i)$ of $V$, which means that the $(v_i)$ are linearly independent in $V$ and span the whole space (under finite linear combination). We need to show that $(1\otimes v_i)$ is also linearly independent under left-multiplication with complex numbers (let’s use the [tensor product relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) for this, every rational number is also a complex number) and we need to show that they span the whole space, again under left-multiplication by complex numbers. Hint: if I want to obtain $z\otimes v$, I can start by trying to obtain $1\otimes v$ (with my tensor product rules!), and then I can do a multiplication.

Comment: So i just tried to solve it, a) has nothing to do with the tensor product, just verify the axioms of vector spaces thats not hard...2) i just feel like i just understood the question lol, but is there anything to prove, can we just say the equality as defined fullfills the vector space axioms as shown in a and therefore $\Bbb C \otimes_{\Bbb Q} V$ has the structure of the complex vector space?

Comment: @Tomy Not “as shown in a)” but the question is essentially the same as a), you just need to apply the same thought process to a different vector space (the tensor space). That multiplication is distributive, associative and identity-preserving with the addition structure is basically immediate from the definition they gave you, that addition is commutative, has inverses, and all the rest of it comes from the tensor product construction. $-1,0,1$ are rational and complex numbers, helpfully, so identifying the complex multiplication with the pre-existing rational multiplication is nice